# Jmeter http simple server(plugin) ADD unique line does not work

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

http://localhost:9191/sts/ADD?FILENAME=/tmp/newEventsFlag.csv&LINE=7ddb876ac39c485a&ADD_MODE=FIRST&UNIQUE=TRUE

If i run this multiple times and then do a GET http://localhost:9191/sts/LENGTH?FILENAME=/tmp/newEventsFlag.csv

I can see that the body length is equal to the number of posts I made.
So unique parameter does not work I guess or am I missing something here?
If it does not work is it possible to get the source code to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the simple table server version 2.2.
Should be fix in 2.3